# Using altitude in Geocoder

Tags: android, location, google-geocoder

Is there a way to include the altitude when finding address from coordinate? There seems to only have the constructor

```
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,maxResults);
```

I don't know much about cartology. But since Google gives me the altitude in `Location`, I imagine it's important for accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

No. (Latitude,longitude) already uniquely identifies a point on earth's surface, and the geocoder would not return indoor information such as floor number for multi-storey buildings (yet).  So there is no point for providing the altitude for reverse-geocoding.

Comment: Not true. Think about bridges. If you one road passing under another bridge, you could be told you are on the street above you when you are not.